# Understanding "between... and... "

Tags: prepositions, numbers

> 1. He wrote between 20 and 30 novels.
> 2. The eight thieves served a sentence of berween 2 and 7 years.

Are they shorthand of respectively:

> 1a. He wrote between 20 **novels** and 30 novels.

> 2a. The thieves served a sentence of between 2 **years** and 7 years.

I have this feeling that 2a is correct, but 1a sounds weird. I want to make sure if my impression is correct.

Comment: Presumably the eight thieves served **sentences** of different lengths, so the word needs to be plural.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

> He wrote between 20 and 30 novels.

is correct, and it's short for

> He wrote between 20 novels and 30 novels.

You will often find the word "somewhere" used before "between":

> He wrote somewhere between 20 and 30 novels.

2. 

Your first sentence is correct, but it sounds awkward.

> The eight thieves served a sentence of between two and seven years.

Jail sentences are usually expressed in a specific way, at least in American English. You typically say "he got 3-5 years," not "between 3 and 5 years." The hyphen functions as the word "to" in that case (he got three to five years).

> The eight thieves served a sentence of two to seven years.

would sound more natural in American English.

Based on the comments, I'm adding this to the answer:

If the intended meaning was to say that the eight thieves each served a sentence, and that each sentence was at least two and not more than seven years in length, then you can use "between" if you make "sentence" plural:

> The eight thieves served sentence**s** of between two and seven years.

To me, it still sounds awkward, and I would say:

> The eight thieves served sentences ranging from two to seven years.

Comment: Surely someone could **receive** a US-style sentence, in court, of 'three to five years' and **serve** two and a half, or four, depending on their behaviour and level of rehabilitation?

Comment: The intended meaning of (2) may be that the thieves received different sentences. In that case, it should probably be worded with "sentences" rather than "a sentence."

Comment: @Michael Harvey - Absolutely, yes. But you probably still wouldn't say "between."